# Query to merge results that require count

Tags: mysql, sql, join, oracle12c

Problem statement-

I have two tables 'Location' and 'Visit'.
In the table 'Location' I have details about the city,country,zipcode etc and in the 'Visit' I have details of how many visits were done to the locations mentioned in the 'LOCATION' table.

Below are the column values of the two tables -

### Location Table

```
ID|City Name|Country Name|Zip Code|
```

### Visit Table

```
ID|Visit Date|Visit End Date|Visit Type|
```

**Question-** I want to calculate the total number of visits done for a particular country and for a particular visit type(based on the value of visit type column in Visit table).
Typically this would be straight forward by taking the total number of rows in visit table and using the 'ID' column as the key to join them. In addition to this I want the results to be displayed as follows-

##Results

```
Country Name|Total no of Visits|
```

This is what's gotten me in a bind. I am not sure how I can get the country name here along with the count value of the rows.

Comment: have you tried to group the data by the country and visit type, after you have joined your tables?
you should show what you've tried so far

Comment: Can you update the question to include the SQL query that you've tried? This will make it easier to turn this challenge into a learning experience 

Comment: pretty much the same as what jamie suggested below but I was looking for something without maybe using joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding that the `ID` is the common attribute to join both tables, you could do it with a simple group by operation...

```
select
  [Country Name],
  count(*)
from location l
  join visit v
    on l.id = v.id
group by [Country Name]
```

If you want to split the count by `Country Name` and `Visit Type`, you must add it to the query and group also by this field, but the output won't be as you describe

```
select
  [Country Name],
  [Visit Type],
  count(*)
from location l
  join visit v
    on l.id = v.id
group by [Country Name],[Visit Type]
```

Comment: thanks this worked. I guess I was looking for a solution without doing joins .. is it possible just by using some variation of a 'IN' clause ?

Comment: It would be possible to use some variation of `IN` clause or even `EXISTS`, but the rigth and recommended way to solve this kind of queries is using the standard `JOIN`